# How to enable logging at the initialization of the module in Python?

Tags: python, logging, module

I am having the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import logging
import test_log

def main():
    logging.error("hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig()

    main()
```

where the `test_log` is defined as:

```
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
_logger.warn('initializing ' + __name__)
```

Executing the main script will led to output:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "test_log"
ERROR:root:hello
```

I believe it is because the `import test_log` statement will execute the `_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__); _logger.warn('initializing ' + __name__)`, while at this time `logging.basicConfig` is not executed. Is there a way of solving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't avoid logging at import time, add a [`NullHandler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#nullhandler) instance to the logger in `test_log`. That will prevent the "No handlers ..." message.

Also, you have two calls to `basicConfig()`. Avoid this - have just one call (in `if __name__ == '__main__'`).

Comment: It's nice to have answers from package maintainer:)